# Do Wayland "windows" really have no decorations or ways to position/resize them?

Tags: linux, gpu, window-manager, opengl, wayland

I have been experimenting with Wayland by writing some simple programs that render some basic OpenGL stuff to an EGL surface. This all works great, but I've noticed that when requesting a surface/window (i.e. shell) from the compositor, I get literally a blank surface with no titlebar or way to resize or move the window. I've tried on both the Weston compositor and on a Chromebook. The Weston terminal appears to render its own titlebar/window decorations. Should I just expect to have to create my own titlebar and method to resize the window when writing apps for a Wayland compositor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is indeed to not provide any window decorations from the compositor. See [for example](https://github.com/dosbox-staging/dosbox-staging/issues/650).

(Though some, like KWin, have a custom Wayland [protocol](https://wayland.app/protocols/kde-server-decoration) that allows apps to request their windows to be decorated, or the other way around, but this is not universally supported.)

Expectations depend on whether you're using an UI toolkit or rolling your own from zero – I mean, most regular apps aren't *expected* to directly speak Wayland to begin with, instead letting the toolkit draw decorations along with the rest of the UI.

When implementing your own toolkit, you will likely be expected to use [libdecor](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libdecor/libdecor) in the near future, but roll your own window decorations in the mean time.

Comment: Thanks. I checked out the link, but eh... I don't know if it's a good idea to rely on compositor-specific extensions if you want your app to be portable across Wayland compositors. libdecor seems like a much better solution, but considering my purposes I'm perfectly happy implementing my own titlebar and move/resize operations.